# Measuring quality of random items - probability that quality exceeds a without any assumptions

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric

Say I draw $n$ random items and measure their quality in the interval $[0,1]$. Now I would like to know: If I draw another item, what is the probability that this item has a quality larger than $0.5$?

I know that if I make assumptions like "quality is normally distributed", I can find the best fitting probability distribution. I also know that I could derive a probability distribution from a kernel density estimator and integrate over it.

But what if I know nothing in advance and do not want to make "arbitrary" choices like a bandwith in the kernel density estimator, do I have a chance to give a meaningful answer to the question above?

Comment: Estimating the probability by the proportion greater than the threshold doesn't require distributional assumptions. However, you do have to make *some* assumptions, or the whole exercise is nonsense.

Comment: Ok. Which assumptions do I need to make and how do I justify them?

Comment: Consider for example the proposition that the data are ordered by a magical elf in such a way that whatever estimator you use will give a wrong answer. (While the example is silly, a *complete* lack of assumptions doesn't rule it out.) If the past is not like the future an obvious estimator like the proportion greater than 0.5 would be next to useless at estimating the probability that the next observation is greater than 0.5. ... ctd

Comment: ctd,,, Almost any estimator could be ruined by the lack of any assumptions, while all kinds of assumptions may allow something to be done. I can't tell you what assumptions *you* can make ... you tell *us* what your situation is.

Comment: Ok, I'll give my best. One can assume that the items are independent and are equally distributed. But there is no a priori knowledge about the distribution they are drawn from.

Comment: That we can certainly do something with; it's sufficient for the suggestion in the first sentence in my first comment, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With independent, identically distributed variables ($X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1}$), you can estimate $P(X_{\text{n+1}}>0.5)$ by the proportion in the observed sample ($x_1,x_2,...,x_n$) which exceed $0.5$. This doesn't require us to assume any particular distributional form.

You can also get a standard error for this estimate, since the sample count will be binomial under the assumptions.